# rake db:test:load not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rake

i am working on a project that requires Rails 1.2.6. I am setting up my first test environment, but i get a "rake aborted! Don't know how to build task 'db:test:load'"

when i try "rake db:test:load." is this command only for Rails 2.x? do i need to use a deprecated command?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid I can't point you at the right task but it might be worth trying `rake -T` to show which tasks are available. You can get further information on a task using `rake --describe some:task` if the truncated description from `-T` isn't sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
rake db:test:clone
```